# US-based proxy for testing software outside of the US

Tags: proxy

I work for an international company however most of our customers are in the US. We need to be able to test our product as if we were a US user. The product involves some content loading including short video clips, so I'm looking for a US-based proxy service that we can use. I've tried Hide My Ass but it is too slow for our purposes. Any ideas?

Comment: Use a VPN service or create your own on a US based server, it's fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spin up an AWS medium instance in us-east-1 or us-west-1.

Stick Squid (for proxying) and OpenVPN (for end-to-end security) on it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that, I hope that it'll be enough bandwidth for my needs - couldn't find any documentation of how much bandwidth is available on medium instances. Do I really need OpenVPN or is it good enough to limit the incoming IPs for the server to my IP?

Comment: OpenVPN is more a belt-and-braces approach.  It's what I'd do to protect my company's IP.. depends what's going across the link.. Might as well, y'know.

Comment: In terms of throughput: http://epamcloud.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/testing-amazon-ec2-network-speed.html

Answer (score 1):

Deploy servers in the US.

If your service can already be deployed to a pool of multiple servers, then deploy some in each region, where you have users. Use location aware DNS servers to direct users to servers in the correct region.

If your service is single homed, then put it on a server in the US such that most customers get a good latency.

Comment: Thanks, we do have servers in the US, but some of the services are location-aware and we'd like to test the user experience as if we were in the US, hence the requirement for proxy. The problem is with popular services such as Hide My Ass, we don't get enough bandwidth

Comment: @nickb Just pick one IP from your corporate network range and override the location service for that one IP.